# circular UIView and buttons?

Tags: xcode, uitableview, uiview, uibutton

I'm trying to replicate a button like the one below (YO ap)

[image]

this button floats just above the table view, the view is perfectly round though, you can see this by how the k letters sticks out perfectly from underneath. Is it possible to create a circular UIView? Any ideas how the shadow effect is created too?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make a round view you can alter the view's layer's `cornerRadius` property.
For instance, you can create a square (width == height) button somewhere, create an outlet for it in your viewController (e.g. `@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *bMyButton;`) and then set it's corner radius like so:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.bMyButton.layer.cornerRadius = self.bMyButton.frame.size.height / 2;
}
```

To make the button "float" above the tableView, I believe, you should add it as a subview of the top view (on the same level of hierarchy as the tableView).
And, finally, you can "attach" a view to the bottom right corner via constraints (auto layout). You can read more about auto layout here: [Auto Layout Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html)

As for the shadow, I've never done that, but I guess, you should take a look at other `layer` properties: `shadowRadius`, `shadowOffset`, `shadowOpacity`, etc.

For instance:

```
self.bMyButton.layer.shadowRadius = self.bMyButton.frame.size.width / 2 + 5;
```

Note, that a UIView might not be clipped to it's bounds. This is the case of UIImageView, for example. If you want a round UIImageView, you'll also have to set `masksToBounds` to `YES`:

```
self.imgMyImageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add `UIButton` programmatically.

```
//margin
CGFloat margin = 10.f;
//your image
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"side_menu.png"];
//create a button of custom type
UIButton *circularBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
//set background colour (if your image includes background colour then you may don't need this)
circularBtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:245.f/255.f green:71.f/255.f blue:64.f/255.f alpha:1.f];
//set your image
[circularBtn setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
//dynamic frame
circularBtn.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width - (image.size.width * 2.f + margin ), 
self.view.frame.size.height - (image.size.height * 2.f + margin), 
(image.size.width * 2.f), (image.size.height * 2.f));
//add to self or any other view you want
[self.view addSubview:circularBtn];
//round the button
circularBtn.layer.cornerRadius = circularBtn.frame.size.width/2.f;
//add the shadow
circularBtn.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
circularBtn.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7f;
```

It should look like,

[image]

In my example, I'd the transparent image of size 40x40 (WxH) and @2x.